# Vagrant 'up' fails to load with the following error

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Using Vagrant version 1.2.7 and VirtualBox-4.2.16-86992 for OS X 10.8.4

Did the following :

```
    # mkdir my-env
    # cd my-env
    # vagrant init precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box
    # vagrant up
```

and get the following :

Failed to connect to VM via SSH. Please verify the VM successfully booted
by looking at the VirtualBox GUI.

Any ideas or solutions greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Asking an obvious question, did you check that the VM successfully booted?

Comment: It does. I enabled gui mode, and i'm even able to log in to the console, to run a couple of workaround i found here, and nothing

Comment: Use `VBoxManage list runningvms` or `vagrant status` to check if the VM is up and running. Try to enable debug log `VAGRANT_LOG=info vagrant up` then `vagrant ssh`, see what happens.

Comment: When the VM comes up, do you see a log message saying it's forwarding port 22? Typically, Vagrant forwards guest port 22 to host port 2222 so it doesn't conflict with your machine's SSH server, but it sounds like that may not be working. Either that or the SSH server isn't starting on your Vagrant box.

Comment: When running VBoxManage list runningvms, it lists two vms  "chef-env_chef_server_1376171368" {59cb26e1-3e83-40a7-a412-cb9861d96f6d}
"chef-env_default_1376185983" {9ebbc306-43e0-46b6-b45f-ccd82966fcc5}